# Regex match if before is present

Tags: regex

So I want to check if a input string can be used as a representation of file sizes.
Example; These are valid:

```
15kb
12mb
128b
64gib
12mib
```

and these are NOT valid:

```
12m
0mb
gb
gib
64ib
52ki
```

Everything works except the check for the not valid value `23ib`. Here`s my regex:

```
^([1-9]\d+)(?i)([k|m|g|t|p]?i?)b$
```

So I want to only match the character `i` if the group before is also matched.

Comment: `0b` should be valid (a file can be empty)

Comment: @Cid generally spoken: yes. But I don\`t need zero bytes for my purpose.

Comment: Would strings like`10gb` be valid?

Comment: And why is 0mb not valid? Is it required that 0UNIT is invalid?

Comment: @JvdV that's already the case `[1-9]\d+`

Comment: Understand @Cid, just wondering if it was left out of the valid patterns on purpose. I guess it's not a complete list. We may just assume OP meant to include it (along as some other valid sizes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may make `[kmgtp]` obligatory, but the whole second group optional and use

```
(?i)^([1-9]\d*)([kmgtp]i?)?b$
```

Equivalent:

```
(?i)^([1-9]\d*)((?:[kmgtp]i?)?)b$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l6h5iB/1)

Note:

- `[k|m|g|t|p]?i?` matches an optional `k`, `m`, `g`, `t`, `p` and then an optional `i`, so `i` can be matched without the preceding consonant
- `[k|m|g|t|p]` matches `k`, `m`, `g`, `t`, `p` or `|` chars, you should remove `|` from the character class
- If you use `[1-9]\d+`, you will not be able to match `2b` like strings with one digit number. Replacing `\d+` with `\d*` fixes it since `*` matches 0 or more occurrences
- It is tidier to use inline modifier `(?i)` at the start of the pattern here, since it may affect all the pattern.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just specify your values more explicit? That way you you can erase something like `20pib`.

```
^(\d+)(?i)([kmg]?i?|p|t)b$
```

This includes the 0-values like `0mb` by using \d+ instead of `[1-9]\d*` and it's easier to read for me.

See [here (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/eQaBeu/2).

Comment: *"But I don`t need zero bytes for my purpose."*

Comment: @Cid I've read the comment that it's not required. I asked why it is not _valid_.

Comment: Then that should remain a comment, instead of an answer

Comment: @Cid Did you read my answer? There's more than that in my answer that's different to Wiktors. Please inform yourself clearly before starting an argument. I also pointed out the elimination of `pid`and a better readability.

Comment: I did read your answer. And it doesn't answer the question at all. It still matches `42ib` and you kept the wrong usage of `|` in the characters class

Comment: @Cid The wrong usage of `|` is right, I missed that. Still no reason do downvote my answer out of anger.

Comment: This is not by anger, this just doesn't answer the question. Plus you're changing expected output for your own tastes